# how to decode following code

Tags: javascript, text, cdata

How to convert following code to original lenguage

```
eval(function(_0x904fx1, _0x904fx2, _0x904fx3, _0x904fx4, _0x904fx5, _0x904fx6) {
    _0x904fx5 = function(_0x904fx3) {
        return _0x904fx3.toString(_0x904fx2);
    };
    if (!_0x2a81[5][_0x2a81[4]](/^/, String)) {
        while (_0x904fx3--) {
            _0x904fx6[_0x904fx5(_0x904fx3)] = _0x904fx4[_0x904fx3] || _0x904fx5(_0x904fx3);
        };
        _0x904fx4 = [function(_0x904fx5) {
            return _0x904fx6[_0x904fx5];
        }];
        _0x904fx5 = function() {
            return _0x2a81[6];
        };
        _0x904fx3 = 1;
    };
    while (_0x904fx3--) {
        if (_0x904fx4[_0x904fx3]) {
            _0x904fx1 = _0x904fx1[_0x2a81[4]](new RegExp(_0x2a81[7] + _0x904fx5(_0x904fx3) + _0x2a81[7], _0x2a81[8]), _0x904fx4[_0x904fx3]);
        };
    };
    return _0x904fx1;
}(_0x2a81[0], 32, 32, _0x2a81[3][_0x2a81[2]](_0x2a81[1]), 0, {}));
```

Comment: The code is obfuscated - it utilizes an outside object (`_0x2a81`) to pass variables into the anonymous function and then perform some actions. Without `_0x2a81` the original source (or close there to) is impossible to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the original code we can't tell what this does. However, a way to check the outputted source is to change the `eval` to either `console.log` or `alert`.